# How can I keep the buttons in different screen sizes in the same position?

Tags: html, css

My website has three different title header text in three lines on the right side of the home screen. Which is the picture:https://im.ge/i/coverpage.Q1CmhX and below this three header text (The titles are in the background of the homepage.), I have placed three "Shop Now" buttons. Pictures like https://im.ge/i/Q1C4aJ but when I look at different sized screens, it looks like this: https://im.ge/i/Q1EXXK.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

```css
    a.btn.hero__btn.btn1 {
        margin-top: 103%;
    }
    a.btn.hero__btn.btn2 {
        margin-top: 112%;
    }
    a.btn.hero__btn.btn3 {
        margin-top: 90%;
    }
    .page-width.text-center {
        top:6%;
        left: 80%;

        position: absolute;
    }
    .hero-fixed-width__content .btn{
        position:relative;
        font-size:20px;
        border: black 2px solid!important;
        color: black!important;
        font-weight:bold;
        background:transparent!important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="hero-fixed-width__content">
    <div class="page-width text-center">
        <a href="" class="btn hero__btn btn1">SHOP NOW </a>
        <br/>
        <a href="" class="btn hero__btn btn2">SHOP NOW </a>
        <br/>
        <a href="" class="btn hero__btn btn3">SHOP NOW </a>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basing page layout on an image is near impossible to get right, and even if you manage to do it there's always some edge case where it just won't work. 

I'd recommend using just the picture of the grill (utilizing transparency to keep the detail in the transition) and making the text and yellow part of the image part of the page itself, which would make adding the buttons and keeping the layout right trivial. The transparent smoke on the yellow part would be a little harder to add this way, requiring some absolute positioning and z-indexing, but it'd still be doable and function reliably.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/2yPN7rc.png for a visual on what I mean. Basically layer everything, that will make scale irrelevant.

To confine the actual HTML on top to the part on the right, use a ```max-width``` based on the minimum ratio between the actual image and yellow (width of the yellow part / width of the image) in percent.